# Unable to find profiler option in my Pycharm CE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, profile, cprofile

I wanted to do profiling for my python code written using Pycharm IDE. I created one function which calls multiple functions.

```
def f1():
   #do something
def f2():
   #do something
def f3():
   #do something
def main():
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()
```

I wanted to do profiling for this code. I wanted to know all the ways it can be done in Pycharm IDE. The suggestion says that it uses cProfiler but I'm unable to find profile option itself in Pycharm. By the way, I'm having PycharmCE-2019 version and python3.6. Is there we trigger the profile option to be visible in Pycharm CE?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this feature is only supported in profession edition, see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for comparison on `CE` vs `PE`.

Supported only  in Professional Edition

> *Profiler
>
> Docker Duplicate code detection Code coverage .po files support BDD
>
> support Profiler integration Thread Concurrency Visualization

You can use this as an alternative for community edition, see [Python profiling with PyCharm Community Edition](https://softwaretester.info/python-profiling-with-pycharm-community-edition/)

Comment: I have done what was shared in the link but I'm unable to find the .prof file. Where is that file saved?

Comment: Most likely in your working directory? I haven't tried this way since I use  Professional edition for my needs. You may want to search around for a possible solution if this causes errors